# How to display default attribute filter on homepage / any page

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml

I am looking for a way to  display the default attribute filter on the homepage / any page.
I tried all kinds of settings in the backend (Category Manager and Attribute Manager), but the attribute filter never shows up on the home page. It neither shows up when the category is empty.

Could I do this with a Custom Layout Update in the "Category Manager" and/or the "CMS Manage Pages"?  Do I need to make changes in the local.xml?

Or is this only possible when I change the Homepage into a Category Page?

Regards,
Els

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer navigation is linked to a category (which must be anchored). To be displayed, the category needs products because the filters depends on products.

> Or is this only possible when I change the Homepage into a Category Page?

You can change default Home page by any other page. Go to your Magento back-end, then in *System* > *Configuration* > *General* > *Web* > *Default Pages* > *Default Web URL*. You can set path to the desired page, in your case a category. I haven't test with a category, maybe you should to set technical path to category in this field (catalog/category/view/id/ID_CATEGORY).

Hope this help,

Comment: Brice, I will give your solution a try. Would it be possible to display the filter on any page, and for all products (even if there are no products on that particular page)?

Comment: In theory yes, but it can impact negatively the performance (especially with a lot of products).

Comment: at Brice: thanks, also for the warning. I will give it a try.